# how to fetch hierarchy of my model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance

This is my common model which has no table.

```
class CommonActiveRecord < ActiveRecord::Base

  self.abstract_class = true

  def before_validation
    set_blank_attributes_to_nil(@attributes)
  end

end
```

My other models look like this ..

```
class BalanceName < CommonActiveRecord

  def before_validation
    super
  end

end
```

I want to fetch all superclasses of BalanceName..

This command is returning only one level superclass

```
>> BalanceName.superclass
=> CommonActiveRecord(abstract)
```

how may i get hierarchy of superclasses ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BalanceName.ancestors will give you an array of all superclasses
```